# Python - Retrieving data from web server

Tags: python, django, request

I am making a program where I need to get information from a web server (I'm using Django) and then I'd send data back to the server.

The thing is I can only find ways to get information from the html page of the url I requested.

How could I use a Python script to get data from the web server? (like making a Django db query but outside Django, using only Python) I want to be able to get the information stored in Django without having to go directly to the website (that is, using a Python script).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean to say you want to write a script that will access the database of **your** Django server directly? (See, you say "a web server", "the web server", "the website". It is unclear which server you are talking about.)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you'll want to use a REST framework. The most used are [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/)